# string as a class name

Tags: c#, string, class

I have a class called `cNormType`. I want to create another instance of this class with the name contained in the string `sNT`. The namespace is `QM`. I want to pass five parameters to the constructor for this class (`sNN,sTN,sDN,sHI,sLO`).

I tried:

```
Type t1 = Type.GetType("QM.cNormType", sNT); 
Activator.CreateInstance(t1, [sNN,sTN,sDN,sHI,sLO]);
```

I get 18 errors so obviously I have this wrong. Would someone be so kind as to show me what I need to do?

Comment: Where did sNN go to (mentioned in your intro but not in your code fragment)?

Comment: sNT = "Bob";  create a class bob = new sNT  but sNT could be "Bill" or "Sally" or ???

Comment: sorry - the sNT in the array should be sNN  I will edit to correct this.

Comment: Did any of the answers below give you what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are those brackets in the second statement supposed to be doing?  Is that an attempt to create an array?  That's not how you create an array and you don't need to create one anyway.  That second parameter is declared `params`, which means that you can just pass discrete arguments and the system will package them as an array.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test the whole thing since I don't have all your code, but remove the square brackets:

```
Type t1 = Type.GetType("QM.cNormType");

cNormType newNorm =
    (cNormType)Activator.CreateInstance(t1, sNT, sTN, sDN, sHI, sLO);
```

I'm not sure what you mean by creating an instance of the class using the name in `sNT`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some really wild assumptions here about what you're trying to do, but does this achieve what you actually wanted?

```
Dictionary<string, cNormType> norms = new Dictionary<string, cNormType>();
   ...
norms[sNT] = new cNormType(t1, sNN, sTN, sDN, sHI, sLO);
```

`norms[sNT]` is then how you would refer to each of the instances (Bob, Sally, etc).

Comment: I am confused about where the actual name of the class is associated with the class.  In your first code snippet, it looks to me like the name of the new class will be 'newInstance'.  What am I missing??  Also, I will have a max of ten people in this app and I am tracking their progress on a project.  Other classes will interact with this for things like hours used, progress, etc.  I need to store this info in Bob's class so I don't think referencing the class will be an issue.

Comment: @bnfdvn I *think* you're confusing "class" (the shape and behaviours you want) with "object" (an instance of a "class"). Your "class" is `cNormType`. You want an "instance" of it for Bob, an "instance" of it for Sally, and so on. The `Dictionary` in the second part of my answer is where to store them, indexed by their names, which are in the strings which you provided as `sNT` in your original question.

Comment: You are correct - I was confused.  So if I understand this correctly, I should put sNT in for "Bob" in the 'instances["Bob"] = ...' line?

Comment: Let me backup - explain what you mean when you say I'm 'going to have problems referring to it later on.'

Comment: @bnfdvn Yes, you should actually code `instances[sNT] = newInstance;` in your program. There's no way that you can have a variable Bob and assign to it now (well, there are ways, but they're really, really ugly!) and then refer to Bob later in any useful way. In fact, the use of `Type t1 = Type.GetType` and then `Activator.CreateInstance` is also something of an "alarm bell" that something more fundamental is not quite right, so I've changed my answer to do it how I'd **usually** do something like this.